# unable to get touched x and y positions back

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just started learning how to program for android and cant seem to get the x positions for when someone clicks on the screen to appear in log cat. (im using an emulator if that has to do with anything) when i do click on the screen nothing happens. Here is my program on startup i get no errors. also using a relative layout

```
package com.practice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;


public class PracticeActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{


    int touchX;
    int touchY;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        onTouchEvent(event);
        touchX = (int) event.getX();
        touchY = (int) event.getY(); 

        Log.d( "MOUSE", String.valueOf(touchX) );


        return true;
    }



}
```

Comment: does logcat put out anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OnTouchListener won't get called until you register it with a view. For example:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Find a view in the layout
    View view = findViewById(android.id.content);

    // register the listener
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```

Comment: thanks just tried adding the view and it works perfectly now, by the way on a side note are the values returned like normal pixels? or in dpi

Comment: Integer pixel values in the API are usually in actual pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Integer.toString(touchX) and return false instead of true, other than that your code seems fine. 
Emulator do register the touch events. 
Also there is a utility called as DDMS, located in the tools folder of the SDK. When your emulator is running, use this utility to get the graphical logcat. You can filter messages as well.